# Array.filter() on object nested array not matching value correctly

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, filter, ecmascript-6

I have Two Array with nested objects

```
let arrOne = [{ id:01, name:'haris' },{ id:02, name:'papi' },{ id:03, name:'john' }];
let arrTwo = [{ jobId:03, name:'haha' },{ jobId:01, name:'kaka' }];
```

Now I want to filter out the arrOne in such a way that arrOne **id** is matched with arrTwo **jobId** Like this:

```
arrOne.filter((ele,index) => ele.id == (arrTwo)[index]?.jobId)
```

But it returns **[ ]** empty array, although if I will rearrange arrTwo in such way like:

```
let arrTwo = [{ jobId:01, name:'haha' },{ jobId:02, name:'kaka' }];
```

it will return the matched value.

so what's the problem here & How to resolve this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution using `find()` inside `filter()` to get the result

And for your question,it's because you are using `index`,however the value with same `index` are not the same in these two array. And if you change the  element order in `arrTwo`,then the same index will get some data for you

```js
let arrOne = [{ id:01, name:'haris' },{ id:02, name:'papi' },{ id:03, name:'john' }];
let arrTwo = [{ jobId:03, name:'haha' },{ jobId:01, name:'kaka' }];

let result = arrOne.filter(a1 => arrTwo.find(a2 => a2.jobId == a1.id));


// or with some()
//let result = arrOne.filter(a1 => arrTwo.some(a2 => a2.jobId == a1.id));


console.log(result);
```

Comment: Or rather `some`, since it returns a boolean. It's more "correct" in a sense :)

Comment: I used your code to render an obj, & it works nicely now. Thanks so much!